# Is killing a process a good way to clear GPU memory?

Tags: cuda, caffe

After running a training procedure using Caffe, very often a CUDA out of memory error appears:

```
F0623 11:47:16.616804  6986 syncedmem.cpp:56] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (2 vs. 0)  out of memory
```

By running `nvidia-smi` I see that there is still a leftover process running which has not closed properly. What is the best way to clear the memory? Is killing this old process a good way out?

Comment: "clear the memory" = (1) free the allocated memory or (2) initialize the memory to a known value, such as zero?

Answer (score 1):

```
kill -9 processnumber
```

frees the GPU memory

Comment: Sure, is it though the best solution?

Comment: the flag -9 refer to SIGKILL signal,this flags  force the process to terminate imediately and cannot be be ignored,for more signals and flags ,type kill -l to see the available signals on your distro,for more explanation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGKILL